# Background png not showing up?

Tags: css, image, png

This website ([click](http://justicejewelers.com)) should look like this website here ([click](http://justicejewelers.rcmhosting.com)) for the most part.  The first link is in BVCommerce cart, the second was the initially designed HTML and CSS.  You'll notice on the first link the center content is slightly off center as well as missing the background with the shadow, which is my main issue.  (The image that should be showing up is images/bg.png)

There are a few bugs with the first website but I'm really just trying to get this background to show up properly.

First website CSS: justicejewelers.com/css/styles.css

Second Website CSS: justicejewelers.rcmhosting.com/css/styles.css

First Website Image: justicejewelers.com/images/bg.png

Second Website Image: justicejewelers.rcmhosting.com/images/bg.png

**UPDATE**

I've combined the bar and background gif to save some heartache.  But any ideas on how to get the whole center area shifted to the right properly?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about your main issue, but on the first page I would change the text inside the head. Search robots such as Google will often ignore pages with too much information in the head due to spam protection.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have something like this in the CSS:

```
.wrapper { background: url("images/bg2.gif") repeat-y scroll center top transparent; padding-top: 0; }
```

and it overrides this:

```
.wrapper {
background: url("../images/bg.png") repeat-y scroll center top transparent;
padding-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually, you have two style.css included. One in the <head>, and one via <link> in <div class="widecontentwrapper">. I think both those stylesheets clash on the .wrapper style, and only one is correct.

Answer (score 0):

About background error, Firebug shows no-repeat :

/BVModules/Themes/Painted%20Paper/styles/styles.css :

```
url("../images/bg.png") no-repeat scroll left top transparent;
```

Also, your #maincontent div is smaller than the width of the background image (you have no padding in the first website (1016 pixels versus 960 pixels)

I guess you should remove /BVModules/Themes/Painted%20Paper/styles/styles.css CSS link
and give a try to a helper like Firebug :)

Comment: I've deleted the BV Modules css file and experimented with something - you can see now that there's a background and it's centered right, but I had to sacrifice the first layer of background for this, now there's no swirls.  Do I really have to choose between the wrapper background and the page background?

Comment: I still see the BVModules/.../styles.css link on the first website, line 7.